# In RxJava what is the type of a reduce expression

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Consider the following:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.observables.GroupedObservable;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TypeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Observable<Long> source = Observable.interval(1,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(20);
        Observable<GroupedObservable<String,Long>> sgb = 
                         source.groupBy(x -> (x%2==0)?"Even":"Odd");

        // I'd like to introduce a variable for source.reduce but I get a type error.
        // Observable<Long> sreduce = source.reduce(new Long(0),(x,y) -> (x+y));

        source.reduce(new Long(0),(x,y)->(x+y)).subscribe(x -> {
            System.out.println(x);
            latch.countDown();
        });
        latch.await();
    }
}
```

I can subscribe to source.reduce as if it were an Observable but I can't assign that as its type.  What type should I assign it?

Comment: OK, this just seems to be a bug in the type inferencing.  If I cast it it runs fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are using imports from package `io.reactivex`, which means you are using RxJava 2. In RxJava 2, methods that return reactive streams that have exactly one item (like the result of `reduce`), return `Single<T>` instead of `Observable<T>`.

Most of the methods/operators are the same, and there's even a `.toObservable()` method to convert from the specific to the generic.

Side point 1: your `grouped` operator evaluates the keys, but does not do anything with the results; as there's not subscription on that Observable, no timer will be started.

Side point 2: you don't need the `CountdownLatch` to wait for completion. You can do one of

```
    source.reduce(new Long(0), (x, y) -> (x + y))
          .doOnSuccess(System.out::println)
          .toFuture()
          .get();
```

or

```
    source.reduce(new Long(0), (x, y) -> (x + y))
          .doOnSuccess(System.out::println)
          .blockingGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the signature of the `reduce()` method you'll see:

```
public final <R> Observable<R> reduce(R initialValue, Func2<R, ? super T, R> accumulator) {
```

In your case it'll be an `Observable<Long>`:

```
Observable<Long> source = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(20);
Observable<Long> sreduce = source.reduce(new Long(0), (x, y) -> (x + y));
```

As the code stands in your example, you're doing `source.reduce(....).subscribe(...)`, which already returns a `Subscription` back.